# Why am I getting compilation error in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, java-8, spring-tool-suite

I have opened a project in STS 3.9.5.RELEASE in mac os X, but I am getting compilation error in the editor only . But when I build the project in command line by mvn clean install , it builds fine, even in STS package explorer its shows no error when I do Maven Update. But when I click on the file and open it, it shows the error in **Editor only**. I think this is some kind of generated file..but not sure..

[image]

[image]

Even after doing `mvn clean install` is not generating the classes

Comment: What's the *error message*?

Comment: If it's a generated file, did you tell STS where to find the generated file? How is it generated?

Comment: That looks like JPA Criteria, and you need to make sure that Eclipse knows about the generated sources.

Comment: Why same import is declared twice? Also, sometimes, when we re-import project in Eclipse then it works.

Comment: The generated sources are already mapped..only the Event_ and Shop_ is not getting generated..any idea how to manually regenerate them

Comment: Is it generated via Java annotation processing? If so its possible JDT APT is not getting configured correctly and so its not being generated in the Eclipse build.

Answer (score 0):

Its generated via Java annotation processing..so it was not getting processed correctly via eclipse build...So I did a mvn clean and then mvn install separately..the artifacts are now generated and STS stopped complaining

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar problem in STS.

I chose Menu->Windows->Preferences->Validation->Disable all validators.

Rebuild the project again and STS did not complain any error.